# Steps to add stencil to existing Ionic app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, stenciljs

We have developed our app using ionic 3. We expect more mobile users accessing our website than from desktops and laptops. Hence want the SEO support on ionic where we can modify title and meta description tags with each page. We have tried https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/progressive-web-app-metatags/89282, but it does not work. 
Is the only solution is server side rendering (SSR) ? If this is the case then stenciljs looks like only solution. Has anybody integrated stencil to their existing ionic projects ? If yes, Can you please let me know the efforts and steps to do that. Pre-thanks !

Comment: Considering that Ionic has Angular under the hood in the first place, won't built-in Angular Title and Meta providers work for you?

Comment: Looks like it does not work, as Page Source does not show the modified values. Even for angular we have used server side rendering using node.js.

Comment: To my knowledge, Title and Meta are supposed to work with Angular SSR, though I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my steps:

1. In your `stenciljs` project run `rpm run build`
2. Copy the whole content from folder `/dist` from the `stenciljs` project into `/assets/your-lib-name/dist/` from your ionic project.
3. In the ionic project edit `index.html` and add the following in the head section ( at the end ):

   ```
   <script src="assets/your-lib-name/dist/your-lib-name.js"></script>
   ```
4. Modify each module that needs import your components with:

   ```
   import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [],
     imports: [],
     exports: [],
     schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
   })
   ```